# Python Sounddevice.play() on Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-sounddevice

I am having some problems to play the sounddevice on a Thread. I import the sounddevice as sd at the beginning. Then during running I want to play a tone on a thread using the ASIO sound card. All the configurations I need to do on the thread works well. However, when I want to play the tone I got the following Error:

**sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening OutputStream: Unanticipated host API 2 error 0: u'Failed to load ASIO driver'**

If I initialize the import at the thread everytime I need it, it work. But of course I do not want to do that. Any Idea hot to solve it?

Thanks!

Here a simple code example:

```
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

class Test(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        #-- Configuration of the Tone to be played
        self.fs = 44100       # sampling rate, in Hz, 44100 or 48000
        duration = 1.05  # in seconds, may be float
        f = 200.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float
        self.tone_data = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(self.fs*duration)*f/self.fs)).astype(np.float32)

    def run(self):                       

        #-- Configuration of the ASIO sound card
        #import sounddevice as sd
        sd.default.channels = 2
        sd.default.device = 14
        print sd.query_devices(sd.default.device)['name']
        #sd.default.latency = ('low','low')
        #asio_out = sd.AsioSettings(channel_selectors=[1, 2])
        #sd.default.extra_settings = asio_out        
        sd.default.samplerate = self.fs                
        sd.play(self.tone_data)
        sd.wait()        

w = Test()        
w.start()
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Matthias I added and example code

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your use case for using multiple threads?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a platform-specific problem. I just tried it with ALSA/Linux and it works fine. With ASIO, you probably have to do the library initialization (which happens during `import` time) in the same thread you are using later to create the stream (which `play()` does for you)?

> If I initialize the import at the thread everytime I need it, it work. But of course I do not want to do that.

Why do you not want to do that? Are you aware that the use of `import` in Python is cached automatically? The second time you use `import`, only a `dict` lookup is done and nothing else.

But you are right, the repeated `import` still *looks* a bit strange.
Did you try to do the `import` only once in `Test.__init__()`? There you could also do all the `sd.default` stuff.

If you still have problems during the initialization (or if you insist on having all imports at the top), you can try to use the undocumented `_initialize()` and `_terminate()` functions, see [issue #3](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/3).

If you want to use multiple `Thread` instances, you'll get problems with the `play()` function, which is meant for single-threaded use. But it probably makes more sense anyway to have only one Python thread that does the audio I/O. See also [PortAudio Tips – Threading](https://app.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/wiki/Tips_Threading).

BTW, you don't need `(...).astype(np.float32)`, this conversion is done automatically for you.

And while I'm at it, your line `sd.query_devices(sd.default.device)['name']` will break if the default input and output devices are different.